# How to hide/delete odoobot created tags in many2many_tags

Tags: tags, many-to-many, odoo

*Ubuntu 16.04 - Odoo 12 - VirtualBox*

I've created a custom module where customer service can add tags to their orders in Sales. It is working as intended in the image below. (example: production art, proof, purchase order...)

[image: working]

The problem I'm running into are the Odoobot created tags that look like directories in the list. (web/content/637-6bb307d/stuff.js) These tags confuse customer service and I need to get rid of them.

[image]

How do I hide or delete Odoobot created tags? Where are they coming from and why is odoobot creating them? There is also a long list of them that you can see when you click "Search more..." while adding the tags.

[image]

```
.py    attachments = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment')

.xml   field name="attachments" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

Comment: That aren't tags but attachments. How is this field defined in python code and xml code?

Comment: @CZoellner They are showing up in my list of many2many_tags that's why I'm calling them tags. I need them to not be in the list of tags. I edited my post to include the code. Thanks!

Comment: `attachment = fields.Many2many('attachment.type')` can't be the right code. The above list search looks exactly like model `ir.attachment`.

Comment: Can you activate the debug mode and just hover over "Attachments" (the label not the input field) in your order form view? What does it say for "relation"?

Comment: sorry you're right I copy/paste the wrong line. I've corrected it in my post. The relation is ir.attachment

Comment: Yes so `ir.attachment` is wrong. Why would you want to use Odoo's Attachments as Tags?

Comment: I work for a company and ir.attachment is what was defined to use in the task info. When you say it like that though I see what you mean about how this is problematic... ha. What would be the correct way to do it for tags? and just to squash all doubt... there is in fact no way to get rid of the ir.attachment attachments on the search list if using it as a relation? (I'm still pretty new to odoo)

Comment: You're defining a n:m or many-to-many relation between `sale.order` and `ir.attachment` or "Orders" and "Attachments". There is already a relation between them, but it's a topic for another lesson ;-) Just create your own model for example `sale.order.tag` give it a field `name` and create the relation between it and `sale.order`. Don't forget to create access rights for the new model.

Comment: A (mostly) good example is the field `category_id` on model `res.partner`. Just look into it, it comes with the base module of Odoo. Please don't name your field like this, the name is an artifact from pre-guideline coding in Odoo. It should be named `tag_ids` or `category_ids` but was left to that name because of compatibility. The model behind `category_id` is `res.partner.category` and is has more fields then just `name`, but `name` would be enough for simple tags.

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! You seem knowledgeable on this subject, could you explain to me why ir.attachment lists the web/content/ stuff like that? What are all those files for?

Comment: There is a lot of stuff of the webclient (javascript, less, sass, css, etc.) saved as attachments. No user would see those attachments, because the attachment system works model and db id based. And there is even more, but it's difficult to explain those details in short ;-)